# Is there a way to vectorize polynomial expansion of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Main idea is to have a feature expansion of the elements in an array by having a polynomial expansion of the elements by taking the array to a polynomial power. Let's say I have a numpy array with two elements, [x, y]->[x, y, x^2, y^2, x*y] or [x, y, z] ->[x, y, z, x^2, y^2, z^2, x*y, x*z, y*z] for the power two. I am able to solve this using itertools combinations but it is quite slow (half a minute or so for an array of 100k~ elements. Is there a way to vectorize this somehow to improve the speed?

Comment: First, could you pls provide a generalized description of the mathematical relationship between your input array, and expected output? It's sort of difficult to guess the generalized expectation from just this one example. Second, can the input be an array of any shape, or only a specific shape? Third, can the "power" be any positive integer, or can we assume some limit? Fourth, what is the kind of real-life scale of the data, and for that real-life scale, what is the current observed execution time (which you're considering to be "slow")?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html):

```
arr = np.array([2,3])

exponents = np.arange(4) + 1

(arr**exponents[:,None]).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 2,  3,  4,  9,  8, 27, 16, 81])
```

Comment: This works for the exponent parts but not for the final pair wise products

Comment: What pair-wise product? I don’t see it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement properly.  It's  possible to use numpy index arrays.  Access elements of an array using an array of indices.

```
 a = np.array([ 5, 7., 1 ])
 #              x, y, One                                                        

 a[[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]]         # Note double brackets                                                        
 # array([5., 7., 5., 7., 5.])

 a[[ 2, 2, 0, 1, 1 ]]         # Note double brackets
 # array([1., 1., 5., 7., 7.])

 a[[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]] * a[[ 2, 2, 0, 1, 1 ]]                                            
 # array([ 5.,  7., 25., 49., 35.])
 #         x    y  x**2 y**2  x*y
```

If it's not possible to add a 1 to the input array.

```
b = np.ones(5) 
b[2:]=a[[0,1,1]]

a[[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]] * b                                                              
# array([ 5.,  7., 25., 49., 35.])
```

Both of these approaches could be generalised to additional dimensions.  I assume this must be a requirement if there's a run time issue.

**Edit:**

```
np.random.seed( 1234 )                                                                    

arr = np.random.randint( 1, 10, size = ( 3, 2))*1.0                                       
arr                                                                                       
# array([[4., 7.],
#        [6., 5.],
#        [9., 2.]])

def expand( arr ): 
    result = np.zeros( ( arr.shape[0], 5 ) ) 
    result[ : , 0:2 ] = arr      # Set first two columns to x and y
    result[ :, 2: ] = a[ :, [ 0, 1, 0 ]] * a[:, [ 0, 1, 1 ]] 
    # Set results in columns 2 to 5

    return result 

expand( arr )                                                                             
# array([[ 4.,  7., 16., 49., 28.],
#        [ 6.,  5., 36., 25., 30.],
#        [ 9.,  2., 81.,  4., 18.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think the second approach should work for me, but I am having a hard time figuring out how I would generalize those indexes, say for an array with 1000 elements or so.

Comment: I've shown a way to apply this across a 2D array in an edit to the previous answer.